# Translation of the writing around Gondor's banner

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkien-languages

The symbol of Gondor at times comes with writing around it and I couldn't find a definitive answer about what exactly it means and whether it's "canon" or just something fans do.

[image]

Comment: This is most likely a fan image, I can't recall an official image looking like this. I am trying to find a translation, but I don't know Tengwar myself.

Comment: The issue is I don't know whether this has been written in Quenya, Sindarin or is merely a transliterated version of English.

Comment: Related: [How to read One Ring inscription?](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/q/28/30)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

## It's the Ring Verse.

This is almost certainly a fan image as MPF points out in the comments below. The Gondorians had no reason to display the Ring Verse on a banner, and almost certainly were unaware of its existence in the end of the Third Age, with only Gandalf having read it while hunting for evidence of the One Ring.

**Black Speech:**

> Ash nazg durbatulûk, ash nazg gimbatul, ash nazg thrakatulûk, agh burzum-ishi krimpatul

**English:**

> One Ring to rule them all, One Ring to find them, One Ring to bring them all, and in the darkness bind them.

This is clear from the bottom right "quarter", bottom left "quarter" and top left "quarter" all beginning with the same words, "ash nazg".

It can be a bit difficult to read because the bottom half is actually upside down. I've attempted to provide a visual guide below:

[image: Image of the white tree of Gondor with the Ring Verse in Tengwar]

You can compare the above with the Ring Verse from the books, you'll notice that stylistically they are identical.

[image: Ring Verse from Tolkien Gateway]

For interested parties, I used [this resource](https://waymoot.org/home/tengwar/teng.html) to reverse transliterate the Tengwar characters into English, and [this resource](http://3rin.gs/tengwar) to check that my conversion was accurate by transliterating it from English back into Tengwar. Thankfully I did "Ash nazg" first and the rest fell into place rather easily.

Comment: The Ring Verse would be a very strange thing for the Gondorians to put on their banner, to say the least, so yeah this is probably a fan image.

Comment: @MPF if you reverse image search the tree you'll find that almost 90% of results are from pinterest, for whatever reason. However, a good point and one I should add to my answer.

Comment: @Edlothiad: these days, 90% of all image search results (reverse or otherwise) are from Pinterest. You pretty much have to put `-pinterest` into your search terms, otherwise your results will be useless.

Comment: @MPF ...it would be even more strange to put it on the language of Mordor, which I will not utter here.

Comment: Good analysis. I knew it looked familiar (the two different parts) but I wouldn't have gone through the effort you did, I don't think. Nice job.

Comment: @Pryftan it wasn’t too difficult, although Tengwar is much harder to reverse transcribe than it seems, and understanding how vowels are used was hard enough.

Comment: @Edlothiad Fair enough. I still probably wouldn't have put the effort in though esp for a fan picture. Not unless I was **really, really bored** and had a lot of free time. Studying Tengwar/Sindarin/etc. and even Fëanor runes (etc.) is another matter entirely, however. Ironically these are things I haven't got around to doing yet but then again I've not completed HoME either (I will eventually but I tend to read a lot of other books too). I've read part of UT and most if not all the Letters; The Silmarillion (love it), Hobbit (including first edition), The L.R. and others but much left still.

Comment: @Pryftan, there is no way one person can remember everything they read from all those things. I am not vested enough in a fictional universe as much as I love it to study his invented languages. The nuances are interesting but being able to speak it is of no interest to me. I too have only read up to BoLT part 2, but I've moved away from reading Tolkien.

Comment: @Edlothiad Still I have a remarkable memory (for numbers too as long as they're meaningful to me, that is). I wouldn't say I could remember it all as such but what is certain is once I've read a book I know more or less where to go to find something specific; it's not that I remember it but I somehow 'know' it. Same with opening to a book where I left off - just naturally open to that page. I am still very into Tolkien but I don't know why I'm so into him other than it's such a beautiful world. He'd be disturbed to know that I have memorised the Black Speech (on the Ring) again w/o difficulty.

Comment: @Edlothiad And it makes sense that you might find his languages fascinating as they are - and he created them first, too, as I'm sure you know. I haven't got into them that much, however, because they're not as important to me as the actual world and events etc. (despite the fact they're an important part of it I can enjoy it with knowing just some of it - more than the average reader even but still not a lot).